# How to write a query for selecting from three tables and if the values are null should not select?

Tags: mysql

I have three tables
1) Category_master

```
 CID     CTYPE
---------------------
  1       2  
--------------------
  2       2
--------------------
  3       1
-------------------
  4       3
----------------
  5       2
-------------------
  6       3
```

2) NSS_maste

```
NID    MID    Name      Value
```

---

```
 1       5     Red        86
```

---

```
 2       1     Blue       96
```

3) Sports_master

```
 SID   MID    Name      Cat
```

---

```
  1     4     Walk      Leg
```

The above is my table

I have to select CTYPE, NSS.NAME NSS.value,sports.name, sports.cat from category master,NSS_master and sports_master an it should not select null value Eg: for CID 2 there is no value in NSS_master table so it should not select but for CID 3 CTYPE 1 select name and other values as null

How to implement this thank you

Comment: How are the tables linked to each other? Also, in general, inner joins will return only those rows where the linking values exist in both tables, while outer joins will return even those rows which do not.

Comment: based on MID foreign key

Comment: You don't use those field names for production code do you? They are not very intuitive

Comment: No I wont use this is a sample

Answer (score 0):

Use `Inner Join` to avoid null values:

```
SELECT C.CTYPE, N.NAME, N.value, S.name, S.cat 
FROM Category_Master C Inner Join NSS_master N ON C.CID = N.MID
                       Inner Join Sports_Master S ON C.CID = S.MID
```